# Removing special characters while retaining alpha numeric words

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I'm in the middle of cleaning a data set that has this:

[IN]

```
my_Series = pd.Series(["-","ASD", "711-AUG-M4G","Air G2G", "Karsh"])
my_Series.str.replace("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ")
```

[OUT]

```
0            
1         ASD
2     AUG M G
3     Air G G
4       Karsh
```

[IDEAL OUT]

```
0            
1         ASD
2     AUG M4G
3     Air G2G
4       Karsh
```

My goal is to remove special characters and numbers but it there's a word that contains alphanumeric, it should stay. Can anyone help?

Comment: There is a fairly large discrepancy between your input and output data.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry about that. I updated the code to make it more meaningful. I created a list and convert it to pandas series to get and replace using regex which resulted the OUT but what I wanted is to keep the alphanumeric words based on [IDEAL OUT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `apply` to achieve your ideal output.

```
>>> my_Series = pd.Series(["-","ASD", "711-AUG-M4G","Air G2G", "Karsh"])
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> my_Series.apply(lambda x: " ".join(['' if word.isdigit() else word for word in x.replace('-', ' ').split()]))

0            
1         ASD
2     AUG M4G
3     Air G2G
4       Karsh
dtype: object
```

**Explanation:**

I have replaced `-` with `space` and split string on `spaces`. Then check whether the word is digit or not.

If it is digit replace with empty string else with actual word.

At last we are joining the list.

**Edit 1:**

*regex solution* :-

```
>>> my_Series.str.replace("((\d+)(?=.*\d))|([^a-zA-Z0-9 ])", " ")
0             
1          ASD
2      AUG M4G
3      Air G2G
4        Karsh
dtype: object
```

**Explanation:**

Using [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
((\d+)(?=.*\d))|([^a-zA-Z0-9 ])
```

(A number is last if it is followed by any other number) *OR* (allows alpha numeric)